# How to generate linkage checkbox (C #)?

Tags: checkbox, linkage

initial we will see two checkbox
No.1: Fruit
No.2: Animals

if select checkbox1 then  display
□ Bananas
□ Apple

if select checkbox2 then  display
□ Dog
□ Cat
□ Monkeys

I do not know how to write it with asp.net(c#), (they begin with SQL binding lists), thank you very much !!!

the initial two checkbox is use
Front End:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkFruit_animal" runat="server" 
     onload="CheckBoxFruit_animal_Load" >
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code Behined:

```
protected void CheckBoxFruit_animal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            string sqlstr;
                    sqlstr = "SELECT DISTINCT * From fa";

            MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MySqlConnection dbconn = new MySqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            myAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlstr, dbconn);
            myAdapter.Fill(ds, "fa");

            chkFruit_animal.DataSource = ds.Tables["fa"];
            chkFruit_animal.DataTextField = "faName";
            chkFruit_animal.DataValueField = "faID";
            chkFruit_animal.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Database:

```
[fa]
faID|faname
1   |Fruit
2   |Animals

[teamName]
faID|Tname
1   |Bananas
1   |Apple
2   |Dog
2   |Cat
2   |Monkeys
```

Comment: have you got the output or you are getting any error

Comment: I have updated the code, according to your need.Check it out

Answer (score 0):

Update code

> Front End:

```
      <div>
        <div>
             <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkFruit_Animal" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkFruit_Animal_CheckedChanged" ></asp:CheckBoxList>

        </div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBind" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
```

> Code Behined

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(json);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //get the data from database
            DataTable dtFruitAnimal = new DataTable("Name");
            dtFruitAnimal.Columns.Add("faID");
            dtFruitAnimal.Columns.Add("faname");

            dtFruitAnimal.Rows.Add("1","Fruit");
            dtFruitAnimal.Rows.Add("2","Animals");

            chkFruit_Animal.DataSource = dtFruitAnimal;
            chkFruit_Animal.DataTextField = "faID";
            chkFruit_Animal.DataValueField = "faname";
            chkFruit_Animal.DataBind();

        }
    }    

    protected void chkFruit_Animal_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = chkFruit_Animal.SelectedValue;
        DataTable dtResult = GetData(value);

        chkBind.DataSource = dtResult;
        chkBind.DataTextField = "faID";
        chkBind.DataValueField = "Tname";
        chkBind.DataBind();
    }

    public DataTable GetData(string strValue)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("DtResult");
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * From teamName where faId=@value";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con))
            {
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", strValue);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Still can't run means...You getting any error...share error which you are facing